# How to normalize the data to [0, 1] in R with data similar to χ²-distribution

Tags: r, scale, normalization

I want to normalize the data to [0,1], but the distribution of this array is quite not regular, having large quantity of low values and small quantity of large values, almost 80% values of data are in the range of `[min(data), 3*min(data)/4+1*max(data)/4]`, and the distribution of data in this range is quite like to *normal distribution*.

so the whole dataset is similar to* χ²-distribution*(due to the low reputation, I can't upload the plot(density(data)) picture).
The information of this data is listed as below,

```
 > max(data)
 > 25418
 > min(data)
 > 104
 > length(data)
 > 971
 > plot(density(data))
```

I have try use the method of dividing the whole data by *max(x) - min(x)*

```
normalized <- function(data){
    return (apply(data, FUN = function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}
```

and scale in R

```
data <- scale(data)
```

But the first method will has a great impact on the majority of lower data by shrinking them close to 0, which will lose a lot of data information, and the second method does scale the data between [0, 1].

So the method of normalization I'm looking for, can make sure the large values closes to 1, and in the same time can also present the major values well(don't shrink them too much).

So wish somebody can light me.

Comment: Depends on whether you will accept a linear normalization or not.  If you don't want linear normalization, you better have a good reason, and "lots of small values" isn't a good reason.

Comment: set min as zero always, those are positive quantities, right?

Comment: Because the distribution of the data is really uneven, almost 80% of the data is in the range of `[min(data), 3*min(data)/4+1*max(data)/4]` or maybe more extreme. And for the data, if the value is too much big value just means it is very significant, the specific value of it might not that important compared with the large quantity of lower values. So I merely want set those kind of bigger value close to 1, and don't shrink the lower values too much.

Comment: I'm afraid this is still not a very clearly defined question.  I would vote to close/migrate to CrossValidated, but I would like to see it improved first/instead.  Can you explain more about **why** you want to normalize the data, i.e. what you want to do with it afterward, and why the current distribution is problematic?  That could have a big impact on the answer to the question ...

Comment: The reason why I want to normalize the data, is because I want to use this data into a probabilistic model for analysis. Frankly speaking, I want to scale this data to the range between [0, 1], which is using as probability values in the model, and that has nothing to do with current distribution. But when I using the liner normalization, the model doesn't fit the data very well and give a very poor performance, so I guess it might be related to my method of normalization, shrinking the data too much. You think it is more properly if I migrate this question to Cross Validated?